# DNN 7 installation - SQL Server Express invalid database account

Tags: sql-server, dotnetnuke

I was trying to install DNN 7 via web platform installer (5.0) but an error came up on install - the specified password for the user account `sa` is not valid, or failed to connect to the database server.

I have SQL Server 2014 but not Express. I don't have a database set up called `sa` or a database server called `.\SQLExpress`.

what would I need to do to satisfy DNN's request for password for `sa` account ?

edit..webconfig

```
<configuration>
  <!-- register local configuration handlers -->
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="dotnetnuke">
      <!-- the requirePermission attribute will cause a syntax warning - please ignore - it is required for Medium Trust support-->
      <section name="data" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke"/>
      <section name="logging" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke"/>
      <section name="scheduling" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke"/>
      <section name="htmlEditor" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke"/>
      <section name="navigationControl" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke"/>
      <section name="searchIndex" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke"/>
      <section name="searchDataStore" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke"/>
      <section name="friendlyUrl" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke"/>
      <section name="caching" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke"/>
      <section name="authentication" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke"/>
      <section name="members" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke"/>
      <section name="roles" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke"/>
      <section name="profiles" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke"/>
      <section name="permissions" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke"/>
      <section name="moduleCaching" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="outputCaching" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="folder" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="clientcapability" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="sitemap" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor">
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <!-- Connection String for SQL Server 2008/2012 Express -->
    <add name="SiteSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <!-- Connection String for SQL Server 2008/2012
    <add name="SiteSqlServer" connectionString="Server=(local);Database=DotNetNuke;uid=;pwd=;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
    -->
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <!-- Connection String for SQL Server 2008/2012 Express - kept for backwards compatability - legacy modules   -->
    <add key="SiteSqlServer" value="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;"/>
    <!-- Connection String for SQL Server 2008/2012 - kept for backwards compatability - legacy modules
    <add key="SiteSqlServer" value="Server=(local);Database=DotNetNuke;uid=;pwd=;"/>
    -->
    <add key="InstallTemplate" value="DotNetNuke.install.config"/>
    <add key="AutoUpgrade" value="true"/>
    <add key="UseInstallWizard" value="true"/>
    <add key="InstallMemberRole" value="true"/>
    <add key="ShowMissingKeys" value="false"/>
    <add key="EnableCachePersistence" value="false"/>
    <add key="HostHeader" value=""/>
    <!-- Host Header to remove from URL so "www.mydomain.com/johndoe/Default.aspx" is treated as "www.mydomain.com/Default.aspx" -->
    <add key="RemoveAngleBrackets" value="false"/>
    <!--optionally strip angle brackets on public login and registration screens-->
    <add key="PersistentCookieTimeout" value="0"/>
    <!--use as persistent cookie expiration. Value is in minutes, and only active if a non-zero figure-->
    <!-- set UsePortNumber to true to preserve the port number if you're using a port number other than 80 (the standard)
        <add key="UsePortNumber" value="true" /> -->
    <!-- Services Framework Tracing is primarily useful for developing and debugging -->
    <add key="EnableServicesFrameworkTracing" value="false" />
      <add key="UpdateServiceUrl" value="http://update.dotnetnuke.com" />
    <add key="Telerik.Web.UI.ScriptFolders" value="~/Portals;" />
    <add key="Telerik.Web.SkinsAssembly" value="Telerik.Web.UI.Skins, Version=2013.2.717.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="loginUrl" value="~/Login.aspx" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="DotNetNuke.Web.Razor.DotNetNukeWebPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="WebMatrix.Data" />
        <add namespace="Microsoft.Web.Helpers" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <!-- The system.webServer section is required for IIS7 compatability It is ignored by IIS6-->
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
    <modules>
      <add name="RequestFilter" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.RequestFilter.RequestFilterModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      <add name="UrlRewrite" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.UrlRewriteModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      <add name="MobileRedirect" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.MobileRedirectModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      <add name="Exception" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.Exceptions.ExceptionModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      <add name="UsersOnline" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.UsersOnline.UsersOnlineModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      <add name="DNNMembership" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.Membership.MembershipModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      <add name="Personalization" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.Personalization.PersonalizationModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      <add name="Analytics" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.Analytics.AnalyticsModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      <add name="Services" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.Services.ServicesModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" />
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
      <add name="LogoffHandler*" path="Logoff.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Authentication.LogOffHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add name="RSSHandler" path="RSS.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Syndication.RssHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add name="LinkClickHandler" path="LinkClick.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.FileSystem.FileServerHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add name="CaptchaHandler" path="*.captcha.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.UI.WebControls.CaptchaHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" path="ChartImage.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="UserProfilePageHandler" path="User.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.UserProfile.UserProfilePageHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add name="RadProgressHandler" verb="*" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.Upload.RadUploadProgressHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add name="UserProfilePicHandler" path="ProfilePic.ashx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.UserProfile.UserProfilePicHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <add name="SitemapHandler" path="Sitemap.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Sitemap.SitemapHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web>
    <machineKey validationKey="F9D1A2D3E1D3E2F7B3D9F90FF3965ABDAC304902" decryptionKey="F9D1A2D3E1D3E2F7B3D9F90FF3965ABDAC304902F8D923AC" decryption="3DES" validation="SHA1"/>
    <!-- set code access security trust level - this is generally set in the machine.config -->
    <trust level="Full" originUrl=".*" />
    <!-- set debugmode to false for running application -->
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" targetFramework="4.0">
      <buildProviders>
        <remove extension=".resx" />
        <remove extension=".resources" />
      </buildProviders>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
      </assemblies>
      <expressionBuilders >
        <add expressionPrefix="dnnLoc" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Localization.LocalizationExpressionBuilder, DotNetNuke"/>
      </expressionBuilders>
    </compilation>
    <!-- permits errors to be displayed for remote clients -->
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />
    <!-- Forms or Windows authentication -->
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".DOTNETNUKE" protection="All" timeout="60" cookieless="UseCookies"/>
    </authentication>
    <!--
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows">
    </authentication>
    -->
    <!-- allow large file uploads -->
    <httpRuntime shutdownTimeout="120" executionTimeout="1200" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true" maxRequestLength="29296" requestLengthDiskThreshold="81920" requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,:,\,?" enableVersionHeader="false"   requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" domain=""/>
    <!--  GLOBALIZATION
    This section sets the globalization settings of the application. 
    Utf-8 is not supported on Netscape 4.x 
    If you need netscape compatiblity leave iso-8859-1.
    UTF-8 is recommended for complex languages
    -->
    <globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en" requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" fileEncoding="UTF-8"/>
    <!--<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en"  fileEncoding="iso-8859-1" requestEncoding="iso-8859-1" responseEncoding="iso-8859-1"/>-->
    <!-- page level options -->
    <pages validateRequest="false" enableViewStateMac="true" enableEventValidation="true" viewStateEncryptionMode="Always">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.ComponentModel"/>
        <add namespace="System.Data"/>
        <add namespace="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
        <add namespace="System.Drawing"/>
        <add namespace="Microsoft.VisualBasic"/>
        <add namespace="System.Globalization"/>
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Services.Localization"/>
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Entities.Users"/>
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke"/>
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Common"/>
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Data"/>
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Framework"/>
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Modules"/>
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Security"/>
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Services"/>
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.UI"/>
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals"/>
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities"/>
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions"/>
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs"/>
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <!-- ASP.NET 2 Membership/Profile/Role and AnonymousAuthentication Providers -->
    <!-- anonymousIdentification configuration:
          enabled="[true|false]"                              Feature is enabled?
          cookieName=".ASPXANONYMOUS"                         Cookie Name
          cookieTimeout="100000"                              Cookie Timeout in minutes
          cookiePath="/"                                      Cookie Path
          cookieRequireSSL="[true|false]"                     Set Secure bit in Cookie
          cookieSlidingExpiration="[true|false]"              Reissue expiring cookies?
          cookieProtection="[None|Validation|Encryption|All]" How to protect cookies from being read/tampered
          domain="[domain]"                                   Enables output of the "domain" cookie attribute set to the specified value
        -->
    <anonymousIdentification enabled="true" cookieName=".ASPXANONYMOUS" cookieTimeout="100000" cookiePath="/" cookieRequireSSL="false" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" cookieProtection="None" domain=""/>
    <membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <!-- Configuration for AspNetSqlMembershipProvider:
                connectionStringName="string"               Name corresponding to the entry in <connectionStrings> section where the connection string for the provider is specified
                maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="int"            The number of failed password attempts, or failed password answer attempts that are allowed before locking out a user?s account
                passwordAttemptWindow="int"                 The time window, in minutes, during which failed password attempts and failed password answer attempts are tracked
                enablePasswordRetrieval="[true|false]"      Should the provider support password retrievals
                enablePasswordReset="[true|false]"          Should the provider support password resets
                requiresQuestionAndAnswer="[true|false]"    Should the provider require Q & A
                minRequiredPasswordLength="int"             The minimum password length
                minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="int"  The minimum number of non-alphanumeric characters
                applicationName="string"                    Optional string to identity the application: defaults to Application Metabase path
                requiresUniqueEmail="[true|false]"          Should the provider require a unique email to be specified
                passwordFormat="[Clear|Hashed|Encrypted]"   Storage format for the password: Hashed (SHA1), Clear or Encrypted (Triple-DES)
                description="string"                        Description of what the provider does
                -->
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="SiteSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" applicationName="DotNetNuke" description="Stores and retrieves membership data from the local Microsoft SQL Server database"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
  </system.web>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="bin;bin\HttpModules;bin\Providers;bin\Modules;bin\Support;"/>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.Web.UI" publicKeyToken="121fae78165ba3d4" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2008.0.0.0-2020.0.0.0" newVersion="2013.2.717.40" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

  <dotnetnuke>
    <htmlEditor defaultProvider="DotNetNuke.RadEditorProvider">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="DotNetNuke.RadEditorProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Providers.RadEditorProvider.EditorProvider, DotNetNuke.RadEditorProvider" providerPath="~/DesktopModules/Admin/RadEditorProvider" />
        </providers>
    </htmlEditor>
    <navigationControl defaultProvider="DNNMenuNavigationProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="DNNDropDownNavigationProvider" type="DotNetNuke.NavigationControl.DNNDropDownNavigationProvider, DotNetNuke.DNNDropDownNavigationProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\NavigationProviders\DNNDropDownNavigationProvider\"/>
        <add name="ASP2MenuNavigationProvider" type="DotNetNuke.NavigationControl.ASP2MenuNavigationProvider, DotNetNuke.ASP2MenuNavigationProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\NavigationProviders\ASP2MenuNavigationProvider\"/>
        <add name="DNNMenuNavigationProvider" type="DotNetNuke.NavigationControl.DNNMenuNavigationProvider, DotNetNuke.DNNMenuNavigationProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\NavigationProviders\DNNMenuNavigationProvider\"/>
        <add name="DNNTreeNavigationProvider" type="DotNetNuke.NavigationControl.DNNTreeNavigationProvider, DotNetNuke.DNNTreeNavigationProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\NavigationProviders\DNNTreeNavigationProvider\"/>
        <add name="SolpartMenuNavigationProvider" type="DotNetNuke.NavigationControl.SolpartMenuNavigationProvider, DotNetNuke.SolpartMenuNavigationProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\NavigationProviders\SolpartMenuNavigationProvider\"/>
      </providers>
    </navigationControl>
    <searchIndex defaultProvider="ModuleIndexProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="ModuleIndexProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Search.ModuleIndexer, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\SearchProviders\ModuleIndexer\"/>
      </providers>
    </searchIndex>
    <searchDataStore defaultProvider="SearchDataStoreProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SearchDataStoreProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Search.SearchDataStore, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\SearchProviders\SearchDataStore\"/>
      </providers>
    </searchDataStore>
    <data defaultProvider="SqlDataProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SqlDataProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke" connectionStringName="SiteSqlServer" upgradeConnectionString="" providerPath="~\Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider\" objectQualifier="dnn_" databaseOwner="dbo"/>
      </providers>
    </data>
    <logging defaultProvider="DBLoggingProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="DBLoggingProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Log.EventLog.DBLoggingProvider, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\LoggingProviders\DBLoggingProvider\"/>
      </providers>
    </logging>
    <scheduling defaultProvider="DNNScheduler">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="DNNScheduler" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Scheduling.DNNScheduler, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\SchedulingProviders\DNNScheduler\" debug="false" maxThreads="1" />
      </providers>
    </scheduling>
    <friendlyUrl defaultProvider="DNNFriendlyUrl">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="DNNFriendlyUrl" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Url.FriendlyUrl.DNNFriendlyUrlProvider, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" includePageName="true" regexMatch="[^a-zA-Z0-9 _-]" urlFormat="advanced"/>
      </providers>
    </friendlyUrl>
    <caching defaultProvider="FileBasedCachingProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="FileBasedCachingProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Cache.FBCachingProvider, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\CachingProviders\FileBasedCachingProvider\"/>
      </providers>
    </caching>
    <authentication defaultProvider="ADSIAuthenticationProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="ADSIAuthenticationProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Authentication.ActiveDirectory.ADSI.ADSIProvider, DotNetNuke.Authentication.ActiveDirectory" providerPath="~\Providers\AuthenticationProviders\ADSIProvider\"/>
      </providers>
    </authentication>
    <members defaultProvider="AspNetMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetMembershipProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Security.Membership.AspNetMembershipProvider, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\MembershipProviders\AspNetMembershipProvider\"/>
      </providers>
    </members>
    <roles defaultProvider="DNNRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="DNNRoleProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Security.Roles.DNNRoleProvider, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\MembershipProviders\DNNMembershipProvider\"/>
      </providers>
    </roles>
    <profiles defaultProvider="DNNProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="DNNProfileProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Security.Profile.DNNProfileProvider, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\MembershipProviders\DNNProfileProvider\"/>
      </providers>
    </profiles>
    <permissions defaultProvider="CorePermissionProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="CorePermissionProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Security.Permissions.CorePermissionProvider, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\PermissionProviders\CorePermissionProvider\" />
      </providers>
    </permissions>
    <moduleCaching defaultProvider="FileModuleCachingProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="FileModuleCachingProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.ModuleCache.FileProvider, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\ModuleCachingProviders\FileModuleCachingProvider\" />
        <add name="MemoryModuleCachingProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.ModuleCache.MemoryProvider, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\ModuleCachingProviders\MemoryModuleCachingProvider\" />
      </providers>
    </moduleCaching>
    <outputCaching defaultProvider="FileOutputCachingProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </outputCaching>
    <folder defaultProvider="StandardFolderProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="StandardFolderProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.FileSystem.StandardFolderProvider, DotNetNuke" />
        <add name="SecureFolderProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.FileSystem.SecureFolderProvider, DotNetNuke" />
        <add name="DatabaseFolderProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.FileSystem.DatabaseFolderProvider, DotNetNuke" />
      </providers>
    </folder>
    <clientcapability defaultProvider="FiftyOneClientCapabilityProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="FiftyOneClientCapabilityProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Providers.FiftyOneClientCapabilityProvider.FiftyOneClientCapabilityProvider, DotNetNuke.Providers.FiftyOneClientCapabilityProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\ClientCapabilityProviders\FiftyOneClientCapabilityProvider\" />
      </providers>
    </clientcapability>
    <sitemap defaultProvider="coreSitemapProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="coreSitemapProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Sitemap.CoreSitemapProvider, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\MembershipProviders\Sitemap\CoreSitemapProvider\" />
      </providers>
    </sitemap>
  </dotnetnuke>
</configuration>
```

**edit - code added to web.config on DNN but still asking me for SQL Express - sa account and .SQL\Express account.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SiteSqlServer" 
         connectionString="Data Source=ANDREWSSD\MSSQLSERVER_EXPR;Initial Catalog=DotNetNuke;User ID=aindriu;Password=;"       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>



    <add key="SiteSqlServer" value="Data Source=ANDREWSSD\MSSQLSERVER_EXPR;Initial Catalog=DotNetNuke;User ID=aindriu;Password=;" />
```

Comment: can you post the database configuration which you added in DNN. '.\SQLExpress' is the instance of your sql server which may or may not be SQL Server 2014 Express Edition.

Comment: i don't have sql express installed, i have the full version.  when i tried installing express on my machine i couldn't find it.  can i set database configuration on DNN ? i didn't set anything on it.

Comment: do i need to set up a database on my machine ? i don't have the login for DNN that it is asking (user sa)

Comment: is your sql server instance on network? what is the configuration in your web.config file of DNN?

Comment: i have sql server installed on my local machine. i didn't make any changes to the webconfig .. you can view it here https://www.dropbox.com/s/qth3y65ns4zv5tt/web.config?dl=0

Comment: Can you please add the contents of your `webconfig` to your question by editing it.

Comment: i added the config file

Answer (score 1):

Open c:\websites\dotnetnuke7\web.config in Notepad and update connection strings in two places. Replace the entire “connectionStrings” section with this fragment (change to your password):

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SiteSqlServer" 
         connectionString="Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=ServerUserID;Password=DBPassword"       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and put the same connection string into “appSettings” section:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="SiteSqlServer" value="Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=ServerUserID;Password=DBPassword" />
 ...
 ...
</appSettings>
```

Make sure you have to change **ServerName**, **DatabaseName**, **UserverUserID** and **DBPassword** with your original database details.

Comment: I changed the details on web.config but its still asking me for the same .sa account and  .SQL\Express details - but it is not giving me an option of remote SQL Server... no matter what though the same login details are required.

Comment: Do you have `sa` user in your SQL database? and do you want to install database on live server? Why do you want remote SQL server connection?

Comment: I don't have a sa user in my SQL database... i don't want a remote server either but it came up as an option once I edited the web.config..  Is there a way I can create/enable the sa user on SQL management studio ?

Comment: There is no any restriction about server username. You can try other users also. Do you have other user for login in SQL Server? Try that one and make sure you must have blank database created in SQL Server which you mentioned in your connection string.

Comment: it keeps looking for database Server: .\SQLExpress which I don't have.. I though the changes I made in the web config would stop it from looking for that ?

Comment: Comment that `\SQLExpress` connection string. We don't need connection string twice in web config file. Please make it as my answer. There are only one connection string in `<connectionStrings>` section and one in `<appSettings>` section.